# I cant get rid of this unresolved reference error while doing the intro to debugging on the google kotlin codelab

Tags: android, kotlin

i have tried looking through this website as well as others. And i have been stumped on this for about two days now. If anyone has any idea as to what im doing wrong here it would be greatly appreciated.

here is the code

```
fun division() = with(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())){

    val numerator = 60
    var denominator = 4
    repeat(4) {i->
        postDelayed({
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_textview).setText("${numerator / denominator}")
            Log.v(TAG, "${numerator / denominator}")
            denominator--
        },i*3000L)


    }
}

fun logging() {
    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: a serious error like an app crash")
    Log.w(TAG, "WARN: warns about the potential for serious errors")
    Log.i(TAG, "INFO: reporting technical information, such as an operation succeeding")
    Log.d(TAG, "DEBUG: reporting technical information useful for debugging")
    Log.v(TAG, "VERBOSE: more verbose than DEBUG logs")
}



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d(TAG,"this where the app crashed before")
        val helloTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.division_textview )
        Log.d(TAG, "this should be logged if the bug is fixed ")
        helloTextView.text= "Hello, debugging "
        logging()
        division()


    }


}
```

and here are the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-intro-debugging?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-four%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-intro-debugging#5) that they provided in the course.

Comment: where's `unresolved reference` pointing on, could you give more clarification

Comment: The findViewById at the top

Answer (score 0):

So AFAIK `findViewById()` is part of the activity class and thus should be called inside the scope of activity or a view
to give you more clarification lets me give an example close to your code
assume the `Activity` as a `MutableList`

#### Using Extension function

---

```
fun division(){
   flatMap {} //Error because its only accessible with in MutableList
}
```

```
fun MutableList<Int>.division(){
    flatMap {} // works because its inside the MutableList
}
```

---

#### Using inheritance

---

```
class mList: MutableList<Int> {
  // Implement the necessary members
  fun division() {
      flatMap {} //works because its under scope
  }
}
```

---

So almost the same Idea applies to `AppCompatActivity`

#### Extension Function

---

```
fun MainActivty.divison(){
    val numerator = 60
    var denominator = 4
    repeat(4) {i->
        postDelayed({
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_textview).setText("${numerator / denominator}")
            Log.v(TAG, "${numerator / denominator}")
            denominator--
        },i*3000L)


    }
}
```

---

#### Inheritance Method

---

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d(TAG,"this where the app crashed before")
        val helloTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.division_textview )
        Log.d(TAG, "this should be logged if the bug is fixed ")
        helloTextView.text= "Hello, debugging "
        logging()
        division()


    }
    fun division() = with(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())){

    val numerator = 60
    var denominator = 4
    repeat(4) {i->
        postDelayed({
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_textview).setText("${numerator / denominator}")
            Log.v(TAG, "${numerator / denominator}")
            denominator--
        },i*3000L)


    }

}
```

new alternatives for `findViewById` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: Thank you so much !!!  I was able to get it situated